# TFS 2015 vNext Build - Set build result

Tags: tfs

How can we set the build result/outcome from lets say a powershell script.

I believe the valid states are Successful, Failed and Partially Successful, but especially for the last, how can we set that one manually. if we return error 1, the script task will have a failed state and the build as well.

We have some scenarios where we want to set the build to Partially Successful.
Im not able to find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to understand:

- A task with a non-zero exit code fails.
- A build fails if a task fails.
- ...unless the "Continue on Error" checkbox is selected, in which case it marks the build as "Partially succeeded" and continues running other tasks.